# The number of parameters depends on the previous activity

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get the parameters that are provided by the previous activities. The number of parameters is not fixed and my method should be able to read all of them (from 1 to n). The number of the parameters is given by the parameter n_inputs. I've tried to do it with the following code, which is correct by the compiler, but it has some problem and I don't know where...I think it must be something related with the array param[ ]. Could you help me, please??

```
    double params[];    
int n_inputs;   

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

    //I'm gonna get the parameters from the previous activity
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    //here I get the number of inputs from the previous activity
    n_inputs = b.getInt("ninputs");
    // I create a new array with dimension "i_inputs"
    params= new double[n_inputs];
    if(n_inputs>0)
    {
        for (int i=0;i<n_inputs;i++)
        {
            params[i] = b.getDouble("param"+(i+1));
        }
    }


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);      

    //Now I try to show the parameters in a toast       
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence text = "parameter 1 "+params[0] +" param 2 "+ params[1] ;
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    toast.show();
}
```

Thank you very much!!

Comment: What error do you get or how do you know that something is wrong?

Comment: The compiler does not show any error...but the activity shuts down when the program try to show these parameters in the toast...

Comment: It's probably an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception. Make sure you are passing atleast two params before fetching them as params[0] and params[1]. Otherwise encapsulate it in try-catch.

Comment: I'm trying it when the previous activity pass only two paremeters...

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Bundle.putDoubleArray()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putDoubleArray%28java.lang.String,%20double%5B%5D%29) and [Bundle.getDoubleArray()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#getDoubleArray%28java.lang.String%29) will be simpler anyway.

Comment: Should it work if I create the variable params in this way: params= new double[n_inputs]; and then I replace the second for with params = b.getDoubleArray("params");

Comment: I don't know...I'm trying in different ways and all of them shut down the app

Comment: I got an inefficient way to do that....I've create so much variables as I could have (4 in my case), and my activity tries to get all of them...if the previous activity does not pass the key...they still zero...It's not efficient but it works. :) Thanks anyway.